# Share iPhone music wirelessly to iTunes

Tags: iphone, itunes, airplay, home-sharing

I'd like to know if it's possible to share my iPhone's music to play it in my computer with iTunes.

I can play my iTunes Home Shared library in my iPhone, but I'd like to do it the inverse way.
My iPhone is synced with my home's iTunes library, and have music I'd like to listen at my work's computer (want to use the computer speakers).
Both devices are on the same network.

Any clue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Two software options (for both Mac and Windows). Both turn your work computer into an Airplay destination, so you can stream audio directly from your iPhone to your computer. This lets you play music from your iPhone without worrying about syncing, copying songs, etc.

On the Mac, there's the open source app called [Airmac](http://code.google.com/p/airmac/feeds). And on Windows, you can try the application [Shairport](http://shairport4w.sourceforge.net/). Both do the same thing, and turn your computer into an Airplay destination.

Once you have turned on one of these apps, start playing a song from your iPhone. If everything is on the same network, you should see the Airplay icon (shown here in the lower right, the rectangle + triangle). Tap that, you should see your computer listed, tap that, and then your phone will stream the iTunes audio to your computer.

[image]